# How do I setup and get started with Appium on Ubuntu?

Tags: test-automation-framework, appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

I have been recently asked to automate flow on mobile devices but I have no clue about mobile automation. I have tried setting up Appium on my machine but to no avail and I find it very cumbersome and confusing. Please suggest how to setup and get started. Step by step detailed instructions please!

Comment: What research you did to answer your question, if any?

Comment: I researched online and found that I need to get ADB Android Debug Bridge on my system. This took a lot of while because I did't want to install the whole Android Studio and just the Android SDK. What are the next steps now for the setup and test execution?

Comment: You have two options: (1) either you follow instructions EXACTLY as written (and hope they are correct and give you promised results), or (2) you ADAPT steps to your exact needs (and then it is YOUR responsibility to understand the consequences of the changes, and deal with them). Good luck. Please post self-answer (what steps you found), it is interesting question but sadly too broad.

Comment: There are like million of tutorials available. Why not research/apply and if you've run in to a problem come back.

Comment: I know there are umpteen tutorials but I found it a tad confusing the setup part in particular. Can you please send a link that guides step by step in detail for setup and getting started with the Appium tool.

Comment: @RohanKalia i spent a lot of time sending you a helpful answer. where's my upvote?? please give me an up-vote and accept my answer.

Comment: @BrianMcCarthy Up-voted, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not install nodejs through apt-get, which will need sudo rights and appium will not work if node is installed as sudo user. If you have already installed remove it using

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

[Download latest nodejs linux binaries](http://nodejs.org/download/)

Extract into a folder that doesn't need sudo rights to access, for example your home folder.

```
tar -xvf <downloaded_binary_tar.gz>
```

Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:<full_path_of_the_extracted_node_folder>/bin
```

[Install grunt-cli](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started):

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Open a now terminal and do

```
npm install -g appium
```

Set up a symlink in your .bashrc file for Appium:

```
  ln -s /path/to/appium.js /usr/bin/appium
```

Test to make sure it can run by running appium in your terminal. The output should be something like:

```
info: Welcome to Appium v0.16.0 (REV 292d265edd9c7aaf96f165009285c814b218363d)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info  - socket.io started
```

[Install Java JRE 6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

[Install Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html):

[Download the SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) and extract it to your home folder.

Launch the Android SDK Manager:

```
~/path/to/android-sdk/tools/android
```

Install the packages that you'll need in the new window:

- Android 4.X
- Android Support Library
- Android SUpport Repository
- Google Play services
- Everything under Tools
- Everything under Extras

You can also create a symlink for the Android SDK Manager by doing:

```
ln -s /path/to/android-sdk/tools/android /usr/bin/android
```